# Haskell: List manipulation

Tags: list, haskell

I want to write a function which takes a input list and manipulates it in the following way:

Step 1: Take the first element of the list and the last element of the list and put it together in a sublist.

Step 2: Take the second element of the list and the second last element of the list and put it together in the next sublist.

Step 3: Take the third element of the list and the third last element of the 
list and put it together in next sublist.

Continue this according to the same scheme (for a list of n elements)...

If the number of elements of the input list is odd the n/2 element of the input list will be added as last sublist of the output list.

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

-- should be transformed to

[[1,7],[2,6],[3,5],[4]]
```

I already wrote a function which takes every 2 elements of a list and puts it together in sublists and I am wondering if this code might help me with my problem above:

```
g2 :: [a] -> [[a]]
g2 [] = []
g2 (x1:x2:xs) = [x1,x2]: g2 xs
g2 xs = [xs]
```

Comment: You could use the `head` and `last` functions if you don't care about complexity: they're O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have to use `drop 1` instead of `tail` here to avoid errors for odd-length lists.

```
g2 :: [a] -> [[a]]
g2 [] = []
g2 xs = [first xs] ++ (g2 . drop 1 $ init xs)
    where first (x:[]) = [x]
          first xs = [head xs, last xs]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's one that does it in one pass:

```hs
pairs :: [a] -> [[a]]
pairs xs = fst (go xs xs) where
  go (x:xs) (_:_:ys) = f x (go xs ys)
  go (x:xs) [_]      = ([[x]],xs)
  go xs     []       = ([],xs)

  f x (xs,y:ys) = ([x,y]:xs,ys)
```

How does it work? Let's look at the first two arguments of go first, and in particular this line:

```hs
  go (x:xs) (_:_:ys) = f x (go xs ys)
```

Those two arguments are both from the same list (`xs`), but we take 2 items off of one, and only one off of the other. Why? So we know when we hit the halfway point. Look at this function for comparison:

```hs
halfway xs = go xs xs
  where
    go (_:xs) (_:_:ys) = go xs ys
    go xs _ = xs

>>> halfway [1..6]
[4,5,6]
```

Now, once we get to the halfway point we'll need to "zip" it with the other list. But it needs to be in reverse! How do we do this? A handy way to reverse any function in one pass is to first write it as a fold. Here's zip written as a fold:

```hs
zip = foldr (\x k (y:ys) -> (x,y) : k ys) (const [])
```

To "reverse" it, you just apply is as a `foldl` rather than as a `foldr` (you also have to flip the closure).

For our uses, we basically build up the base as we go (in the form of `k`). So no our function looks like this:

```hs
pairs :: [a] -> [[a]]
pairs xs = go xs xs (const []) where
  go (y:ys) (_:_:zs) k = go ys zs (f y k)
  go (y:ys) [_]      k = [y] : k ys
  go ys     []       k = k ys

  f x k (y:ys) = [x,y] : k ys -- same `f` as from `zip`
```

There's still one problem: the list is returned in the wrong order. To fix this, we replace the list with a [difference list](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list), and swap the order of the appends.

Finally, we un-CPS the function, and we get the above.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one using `transpose`

```
import Data.List

g2 xs =
  transpose [take (x + y) xs, take x (reverse xs)]
    where (x, y) = (length xs) `divMod` 2
```

Comment: I was about to post a very similar solution, but I used ``splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs``

Comment: Oh nice, that's even better

Answer (score 1):

Two more, the second is using [unfoldr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr):

```
pair xs = take (length xs `div` 2) $ zip xs (reverse xs)
-- Note: uses tuples instead of lists

import Data.List
pairs2 = unfoldr (\xs ->
    if length xs < 2 
    then Nothing
    else Just ([head xs, last xs], init.tail $ xs))

xs = [2,3,4,7,6]
pair xs   -- [(2,6),(3,7)]
pair2 xs  -- [[2,6],[3,7]]
```